# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value when validating content as JSON in WOPI

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat9, ms-wopi

I am currently implementing the WOPI with my application. Our domain is already whitelisted by [Microsoft](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). While implementation I am currently facing two problems as mentioned below:

1. The exception is thrown when trying to validate content as JSON: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value.' I am sending my response "Value=application/octet-stream" but I don't understand why the server is trying to parse the stream as JSON.
2. After every new request coming from "iframe" is initiating a new session in the JAVA.

Here are more details:

My current URL is https://onenote.officeapps-df.live.com/hosting/WopiTestFrame.aspx?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&dchat=1&hid=26D7CA2A10F60A68720106BF599F84B9&&WOPISrc=https://domain/wopiEditor/files/73346e47-697b-11e6-a8bc-c26cd8f74b91/courses/independentConcepts/concept_adminGlo_5/assets/Setting url for static ip.docx&access_token=DEADBEEFDEADBEEFDEADBEEF&access_token_ttl=1532765580679

And My Java code is as following:

```
public void getFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String name) {
        Println.getInstance().log(request.getSession().getId() + "re" + request.getRequestURI());
        InputStream fis = null;
        OutputStream toClient = null;
        try {
            String path = getFilePath(request) + name;
            File file = new File(path);
            String filename = file.getName();
            // XWPFDocument xDoc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
            fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fis.available()];
            fis.read(buffer);
            response.reset();

            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment;filename=" + new String(filename.getBytes("utf-8"), "ISO-8859-1"));
            response.addHeader("Content-Length", "" + file.length());
            response.addHeader("Content-Type", "" + "application/octet-stream");
            //Println.getInstance().log(file.length() + "l" + file);
            toClient = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            toClient.write(buffer);

            toClient.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fis.close();
                toClient.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

The test frame image is attached [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is on the CheckFileInfo request which is supposed to be returned as JSON.  The Java snippit that you provided is for the getFile request which is a separate call that is made from the Office Online server.  You should look over  https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/ for how to write your implementation.

Comment: No actually I am getting this error on every request except starting 4 host frame. So you are saying there needs to be separate callback for every request.

Comment: Another thing you didn't answer the second query why new session is created

Answer (score 0):

One thought is maybe you need to set the Content-Type header more specifically instead of the application/octet-stream you are sending?

Also there are quite a lot of other header values you are supposed to be returning, some of them may matter as well:

https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/common_headers.html#common-headers